# como clicar em uma anchor no Selenium Webdriver (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Tentei clicar em uma anchor para retornar um valor para dentro do meu input;

Tentei usando o **Xpath** e o **link_text** para clicar nele.

Como eu poderia fazer isso ?

**Código python:**

```
    window_segundo = driver.window_handles[1]
    driver.switch_to.window(window_segundo)
    user_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_Arg"]').send_keys('12', Keys.ENTER)
    user_element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("88319561000107").click()
```

**Elemento:**

```
<td class="linha">
        <a href="#" onclick="devolveSelecao('operadora#12,descOperadora#SOGAL,limpaArg#,limpaArg2#,limpaArg3#,limpaArg4#,limpaArg5#,limpaArg6#,versaoFw#,ultimaCarga#,descSituacaoEquipamento#,descTipoEquipamento#,descTipoVeiculo#,numSD#,veiculoAtual#,numSDAtual#,tipoVeiculoAtual#');">88319561000107</a>
</td>
```

**Erro:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"88319561000107"}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você deu switch quando ele abriu essa janela de popup? se não deu ele vai estar procurando isso ai na janela anterior

Comment: sim dei o switch apos o popup e fiz a pesquisa dos valores, funcionou perfeitamente,  só que na hora de eu clicar nesses valores ele não localiza.

Comment: o comando, find_element_by_link_text não serve pra pegar o texto entre as tags, ele vai pegar geralmente o texto de dentro da tag, ex: <a href="www.etc.com" title="88319561000107">  (nesse caso daria certo), você pode pegar por xpath assim: //a[text()='88319561000107']

Comment: Lucas eu não sei o pq mas em algum momento ele meio que se perdeu no switch, ai eu dei um switch para retornar a tela principal e mais um para voltar a esse popup, ai consegui encontrar o elemento usando o Xpath. Eu agradeço muito a sua ajuda...